# Firebase functions in multiple separate folders

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

My source code looks like this:

API/index.ts (includes 1 firebase function trigger)

Extra/index.ts which includes

```
exports.ml_files = require("./ai-func");
exports.authHandler = require("./user-function");
exports.fileUploadListen = require("./fileupload.listener");
// exports.graphql = require("../API/src/index");
```

Currently my functions source directory directory is Extra. How do I make sure that the functions defined in API also get included in the final build? If I try to use exports.graphql the build breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move all source code into the "functions" folder for deployment.  The CLI will only deploy content from that folder, and from nowhere else.  It's not possible to configure it otherwise - you must have a single folder where everything lives.  As such, paths given to `require()` that look outside the folder (as you are doing now with ..) will simply not work.

Comment: How would you properly separate things into separate projects then? Do you normally use separate tooling to paste the projects into the folder like xcopy? We would like to separate the API from other triggers and having that sort of folder structure made sense

Comment: There's no standard for this.  You could look into making a module and arranging for it to be installed into node_modules from some other location.  Cloud Functions will reconstitute the contents of node_modules by performing an install during deployment.